# Javascript lodash Filter Objects in Array based on value

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have the following array of objects:

```
var array = [
  {
    name: isSale,
    value: true
  },
  {
    name: isSale,
    value: false
  },
  {
    name: isNew,
    value: true
  }
]
```

I need to filter the array so that I have only 2 objects at the end:

```
var array = [
  {
    name: isSale,
    value: true
  },
  {
    name: isNew,
    value: true
  }
]
```

Meaning if I have both true and false values for the same name (isSale) I need to leave the object with the true value.

But if my array looks like this:

```
var array = [
  {
    name: isSale,
    value: false
  },
  {
    name: isNew,
    value: true
  }
]
```

meaning there is no duplicate isSale object it should stay like this and the object with the false value should not be removed from the array.

I prefer a solution with ES5 (you can write it in ES6/7 and transpile it with babel to ES5) and you can use lodash as well.

Thank you for the suggestions and cheers!

Comment: please add your attempt. what does not work?

Comment: hi Nina, it seems easy, but I currently can't wrap my head around it as to how to exactly do that, so I have no code currently. I did the filtering so far with `let found = preservedAttributes.some(function (preservedAttribute) {
     return preservedAttribute.id === attribute;
    });` but the logic was just to have each attribute only once (isSale, isNew)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could seach for same `name` in the result set and replace if the former value is `false`.

```js
const
    filter = array => array.reduce((r, o) => {
        var index = r.findIndex(({ name }) => name === o.name)
        if (index === -1) r.push(o);
        else if (!r[index].value) r[index] = o;
        return r;
    }, []),
    array1 = [{ name: 'isSale', value: true }, { name: 'isSale', value: false }, { name: 'isNew', value: true }],
    array2 = [{ name: 'isSale', value: false }, { name: 'isNew', value: true }];

console.log(filter(array1));
console.log(filter(array2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```